# Imageview parameters for positioning and resizing

Tags: android, imageview

Need to insert a banner on the center bottom of the Android screen.

Which ImageView parameters should be inserted, so the user can rotate the screen and Android resizes the image to ensure that:

1. The image ratio keeps the proportionality 1 x 6 (height x width).
2. The maximum image height is 10% of the screen height.
3. The image width is the same of screen width (if possible).
4. Image is centered on the bottom (if item 3 is not possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)

setAdjustViewBounds(boolean): Set this to true if you want the ImageView to adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.

setBaselineAlignBottom(boolean):    If true, the image view will be baseline aligned with based on its bottom edge.

setMaxHeight(int):  An optional argument to supply a maximum height for this view.

setMaxWidth(int):   An optional argument to supply a maximum width for this view.

setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType):  Controls how the image should be resized or moved to match the size of this ImageView.

ImageView.ScaleType     CENTER_INSIDE:  Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

Do you have some code that isn't working you would like to post?
You will likely want both 3 and 4; the image (ad?) should stay centered at the bottom of the screen even if the banner fills the width.